# To Limit 5 data display using php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to view only 5 data. I've tried multiple ways to solve the problem. But it come out no result. Below one way I used to view the 5 data.

```
<?php $idpnbtn = ''; 
        foreach ($lihat_penerbitan as $pnrbtn) {
    $num=0;
    $num ++;
?>
<strong class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>                   
    <?php echo $pnrbtn['gelar']; ?> <?php echo $pnrbtn['nama']; ?>
</strong>
<?php if($idpnbtn != $pnrbtn['kt03idpnbtn']) { ?>

<h5 class="text-justify ">
    <?php echo $pnrbtn['judul']; ?><br>
    <em><?php echo $pnrbtn['tajuk']; ?></em><br><br>
</h5>

<?php }?>
<?php $idpnbtn = $pnrbtn['kt03idpnbtn']; ?>
<?php if($num==5) break;}?>
```

Anybody can help ? Thank you.

Comment: you can use limit in your SQL query to limit your result row.

Comment: i can't change the code on my sql because i will use the same sql to view another output on the other page. the other page will view all of $pnrbtn['nama'] + $pnrbtn['tajuk'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // in foreach loop 
 <?php $idpnbtn = ''; 
    foreach ($lihat_penerbitan as $pnrbtn) {
 $num ++; 
  if($num ==5){
break;
  }  
?>
```

look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384989/how-to-display-only-5-records) answer by [@oezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288773/oezi)

Comment: thank you, i've found the answer. but i wanna try this one too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Need to place $num = 0; on the outside of the foreach:

```
$num=0;    
foreach ($lihat_penerbitan as $pnrbtn) {
```

Otherwise $num will just toggle between 1 and 0 and never equal 5.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach (array_slice($lihat_penerbitan, 0, 5) as $pnrbtn) {
```

without `$num`

Comment: i've tried your suggestion, but it loop the $pnrbtn['nama'] and   $pnrbtn['tajuk'] to 5. but actually i want to loop  $pnrbtn['nama'] +  $pnrbtn['tajuk'] to 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's easy to do with query.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: i can't change the code on my sql because i will use the same sql to view another output on the other page. the other page will view all  
of $pnrbtn['nama'] + $pnrbtn['tajuk'].

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer :)

```
          <?php $idpnbtn = '';
            $num=0; 
                      foreach ($lihat_penerbitan as $pnrbtn) {


               ?>
                <strong class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>                   
                    <?php echo $pnrbtn['gelar']; ?> <?php echo $pnrbtn['nama']; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if($idpnbtn != $pnrbtn['kt03idpnbtn']) { 
                $num ++; ?>

                <h5 class="text-justify ">
                    <?php echo $pnrbtn['judul']; ?><br>
                    <em><?php echo $pnrbtn['tajuk']; ?></em><br><br>
                </h5>

                <?php }?>
                <?php $idpnbtn = $pnrbtn['kt03idpnbtn']; ?>
              <?php if($num==5) break;}?>
```

Thank you for your help !